# Bootstrap Dropdown Button with Block Level?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a bootstrap 3 **dropdown** button accept the full width (.btn-block class) properties. It doesn't seem to work the same way with the drop down button as it does with regular buttons. Here is my current code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Dealer Tools  <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Dealer Area</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> App Registration</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Single button -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="http://www.agrigro.com/testarea/contact-us/">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  CONTACT US
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get this to work right so the dropdown button takes up the full col-6?

Comment: I see you've got a `<button>` inside an `<a>`. You shouldn't do that. Never nest interactive elements.

Comment: Oh? really? what would be better? applying the button class to the a element?

Comment: That depends on what you want. If you want the user to click the button, don't put it in an `<a>`. And vice versa. If you want a link, but have it look like a `<button>`, use only an `<a>` and apply some styles to it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apply `btn-block` to both the `btn-group` and `btn`

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Dealer Tools  <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Dealer Area</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> App Registration</a></li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/101166

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! 
P.S. to anyone... To make the menu dropdown items also full width add btn-block to the class in <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

Answer (score 22):

When using a drop down, apply btn-block to btn-group first, then you can add col-?-? in the button's class to control the width of the button sections.  Handy little trick.

```
 <!-- Split button -->
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
      <button type="button" class="btn col-lg-10 btn-lg btn-danger">Action</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn col-lg-2 btn-lg btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great answer, this is the true bootstrap way of doing it!

Answer (score 10):

[image]

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="col-lg-10">
            Button dropdown
        </span> 
        <span class="col-lg-2">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For **single button dropdown** @Skelly [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646616/188574) works. For the **split button dropdown**, I got the answer from *Dave Ward*'s [Using btn-block with Bootstrap 3 dropdown button groups](http://encosia.com/using-btn-block-bootstrap-3-dropdown-button-groups/).

He uses `col-*-*` for split buttons

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">Approve</button>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button class="col-sm-10 btn btn-lg btn-danger">Deny</button>

    <button class="col-sm-2 btn btn-lg btn-danger dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu btn-block">
      <li><a href="#">Reason 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reason 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Reason 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different setup, but what worked for me using Javascript, React Bootstrap 1.3.0, and React 16.9.0, was to apply block parameter to both the Dropdown and the Dropdown.Toggle:

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

<Dropdown block>
  <Dropdown.Toggle block> Label for the button when collapsed </Dropdown.Toggle>
  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item>Option 1</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item>Option 2</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item>Option 3</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```